# SQL XML Attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm trying to figure out how to get an XML attributes value when the element name changes. The attribute will be the same regardless of the element.

```
<obj1 id="1" name="sally" />
<obj2 id="15" date="yesterday" />
```

I've been trying various forms of this, but it's not working:

```
SELECT 
   [OriginalRecordXml].value('(/./id)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')
FROM [AuditRecords]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Querying the XML is done via XPath expressions so you need to show the entire XML you're trying to query to get a proper answer

Comment: Those two records are pretty much how they look. An individual XML record is stored in a table column, so we'd only be hitting one at a time.

Comment: You mean, each tag as a row?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should've been more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this does the trick:

```
declare @t table (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    XMLData xml not null
);

insert into @t (XMLData)
values (N'<obj1 id="1" name="sally" />
<obj2 id="15" date="yesterday" />'),
(N'<objM />');

select t.Id, x.c.value('./@id', 'varchar(max)')
from @t t
    cross apply t.XMLData.nodes('//*[@id]') x(c);
```

Or, you can save a little bit if you only need value from first / single node:

```
select t.Id, t.XMLData.value('/*[@id][1]/@id', 'varchar(max)')
from @t t;
```

Comment: Trying this: `SELECT [OriginalRecordXml].value('./@ID_Trader', 'varchar(MAX)') FROM [FIRST].[dbo].[AuditRecords]` gives the following error:  `XQuery [FIRST.dbo.AuditRecords.OriginalRecordXml.value()]: Top-level attribute nodes are not supported`

Comment: @DanChampagne, updated the code so that it utilises table as a source. If you need second row in your output (which doesn't match the selection criteria, but anyway), replace `cross` with `outer`.

Comment: Regarding your particular code in the first comment, if you don't specify the node position in the `nodes()` XML method, you need to provide full path in the `value()`. I'm not sure wildcard will work here, though.

Comment: Yep, it does. Added second option in the answer.

Comment: So the second one worked. Is there a way to put the ID field into a variable? I tried `DECLARE @id varchar(20) = 'ID_Trader' .... x.c.value('(./@*[sql:variable("@id")])', 'varchar(MAX)'),` but I'm getting an error on that one.

Comment: Got it! `x.c.value('./@*[local-name()=sql:variable("@id")][1]', 'varchar(MAX)')`,